# Какая правильная ссылка на тег?

Tags: seo, теги, поисковые-системы

Например тег «как это сделать», ссылка которого будет типа **/tag/как%20это%20сделать** - такая ссылка правильная будет и нормально будет восприниматься поисковыми системами?

Или лучше сделать **/tag/как-это-сделать**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в адресную строку этой страницы ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Кратко: `лучше-через-минусы`.**

Не вполне понимаю критериев правильности, но предполагаю, что на Stack Exchange сделано хорошо.

Метка [поисковые-системы](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b) имеет адрес:

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/поисковые-системы
```

Вопросы имеют адрес вида

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438063/Какая-правильная-ссылка-на-тег
```

Стоит заметить, что часть с текстом в URL вопроса — необязательная. Точно на ту же страницу приведет обрезанный:

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438063/
```

Т.е. между пробелами, которые разворачиваются в `%20`, и знаком `-` стоит выбрать второе.

Comment: хорошо ответили, но Visman первый)
если б можно было, поставил бы и Вам

Comment: @emtecif: да пожалуйста, ему полезнее будет. А вообще, плюсы-то можно каждому ставить )